# MongoDB Manual References vs DBREF

Tags: mysql, mongodb, relational-theory

I've been researching MongoDB and trying to see if it would be a fit for my company's product catalog.

I came across database references: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/ and had some questions about how exactly to link documents together.

Assume we have two `db.categories` and `db.products` collections... I have documents in `db.products` that need to link to their categories in `db.categories`.

I have a "category" field in `db.products` that I will store the objectID of the category document in. However, I do not see a way to specify that this objectID references the `db.categories` collection. 
Do I need to use DBREFs?

Below is a brief example of my data...

Document in `db.categories`:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("546b72a47ea1d03593000158"),
        "name" : "Category1",
        "type" : "type1 of category1",
        "spec_columns" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "capacity",
                "display" : "Capacity (tons)"
            }, 
            {
                "field" : "weight",
                "display" : "Weight (lbs)"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Document in `db.products`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546a575f7ea1d03593000154"),
    "model" : "NER003H",
    "category" : ObjectId("546b72a47ea1d03593000158"),
    "capacity" : "1/2",
    "weight" : 10
}
```

Any help, suggestions and advice is welcome and greatly appreciated.

Darius

Answer (score 14):

Short version: use a manual reference, not a `DBRef`.

**Explanation:**

There is no particular benefit to the use of a `DBRef` beyond giving you the collection and database that the referenced document resides in.  If you know the reference is only between categories and products, then that is not particularly useful.  A `DBRef` simply contains the `_id` of the referenced document, the collection name and optionally the database name.  You will usually have all that information in your application (i.e. you have the _id and you know that db/collection it resides in already).

If that were not the case, let's say you had references to documents in a slew of databases and collections and it was difficult or cumbersome application side to keep track of which one each document resided in, then it [may be a benefit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#use) to use `DBRefs`.  After all, the easiest way to do a manual reference in that case would be to store the database and collection that you are referencing in the document too, and that is what `DBRefs` do for you in any case.

That (referencing multiple collections from a single source collection) is not a terribly common pattern though and not what you have outlined above, and so unless you have such a compelling reason to use them, manual references are recommended instead.

[Some of the drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#driver-support-for-dbrefs) have helper methods which may save a few lines of code versus a manual reference, but not all drivers do, and it may make the code harder to understand (without some nice comments/documentation to explain it).  As well as that, the DBREF approach is more fixed than a manual implementation - what if you want to reference a field other than `_id` for example.

Finally, in terms of product catalog design, I would highly recommend reading these two excellent and detailed blog posts from [Antoine Girbal](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/):

- [Part 1 - Schema Design](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/91964246640/product-catalog-part-1-schema-design)
- [Part 2 - Product Search](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/98177689640/product-catalog-part-2-product-search)

There were also three presentations given at MongoDB World 2014 on this very topic, so I would recommend reviewing those also as you progress:

- [Presentation 1: Flexible, Searchable, Low Latency Product
  Catalog](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/retail-reference-architecture-part-1-flexible-searchable-low-latency-product-catalog)
- [Presentation 2: Real-time, Geo-Distributed Inventory](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/retail-reference-architecture-part-2-real-time-geo-distributed-inventory)
- [Presentation 3: Scalable Insight Component (User History,
  Recommendations, Personalization)](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/retail-reference-architecture-part-3-scalable-insight-component-providing-user-history)